# Scaling along local axis after rotating in edit mode does not work

Tags: transforms, shortcut

Scaling along a local axis after rotating doesn't seem to work. If I rotate an object in edit mode and hit <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, the editor says I'm scaling along the local X axis, but it's still scaling along the global it seems. Am I missing something? Using Blender 3.4.

Comment: You are indeed scaling along the local X axis, which happens to remain the same if you rotate in *Edit Mode*.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Thanks so much. After rotating in Object Mode, scaling on the local axes had the expected results!